# SEFlair - an HD, customisable flair for your Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: app, flair

### Updated to provide an image rather than embedded content:

## [Good looking, higher quality Stack Exchange flairs!](https://stackapps.com/q/7395/28139)

#### About:

SEFlair is an HTML, CSS and JavaScript app which you can include on your website.

I created it because the flairs provided by Stack Exchange are:

1. not customizable (the elements are fixed in the image)
2. not HD (less than 200px - and they look pretty bad on retina displays).

This is for anyone who wants to show off their flair on their website.

It uses the `/users/{ids}/` API V2.2 to fetch Reputation, Badge Counts, Display Name and your Display Image. It also fetches the favicon of the site.

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:

[image]

#### Download / Install:

The code is available on GitHub - [timtjtim/SEFlair](http://github.com/timtjtim/SEFlair)

#### Platform:

This is embedded into your website. It should work on all browsers, including IE 9+. JavaScript is required (but if disabled, it fails gracefully).

#### Contact:

I created this code, and am the only contributor. You can email me at contact@timtjtim.co.uk or you can open an issue on GitHub

#### License:

MIT - see licence at GitHub - [timtjtim/SEFlair/LICENSE](http://github.com/timtjtim/SEFlair/LICENSE)

#### Code: (recommended)

This was written with HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

If you wish to contribute, open a pull request on GitHub - [timtjtim/SEFlair](http://github.com/timtjtim/SEFlair)

Comment: Wait, and how do you use it?

Comment: @nicael insert the code into your webpage. There are detailed instructions on the GitHub README

Comment: Ok, but why haven't you included the usage instructions in the question, that's weird.

Comment: Ah, so it can't be used as you do it with the SE flair?

Comment: @nicael I left them out because it's one place to update not two when I change the README. And it can go anywhere you have access to the css, js and html