# Good looking, higher quality Stack Exchange flairs!

Tags: script, flair

Higher quality flair for your Stack Exchange accounts.

Want a flair like this?

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Or even this?

[image]

It's easy! Simply use this URL:

```
https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/SITENAME/USERID/COLOR
```

where `SITENAME` is the site you want to use (e.g. `stackoverflow`, `askubuntu` or `mathoverflow.net`), `USERID` is your user ID on that website, and can be found by visiting your profile, and `COLOR` is a colour - either a hex value or an HTML colour name. For transparency, use an invalid colour. You can also append `/light/` to the URL to use a light text colour - useful for dark backgrounds.

Flairs are cached for 2 hours, favicons for 7 days.

For the first example:

## https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/askubuntu/50/orange

the second example:

## https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/askubuntu/-1/blue

and the third:

## https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/askubuntu/69/292929/light

Comment: Nice, looks great! I just have one small criticism: the font doesn't show all numbers on the same line (look at the 9 in my score on [this flair](https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/literature/481/EEEEEE)). Would you mind using a different font? Thanks for making this SVG flair! :)

Comment: Also, consider switching to a white or lighter color font when the background is darker. https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/literature/481/000000 is unreadable.

Comment: @Shokhet You can now use the same path, but append `/light` to get a  light font (`#E5E5E5`). I've also changed the font to Lato, which is better for numbers. It will take an hour after you last generated a flair to update.

Comment: I'd like to upvote, but... "503 Service Unavailable".

Comment: @dim mmh I should get around to fixing that...